# image from API not showing & yellow strips from list view

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in coding, and I'm having issues with my program. it was working just fine yesterday. The image is not being shown from the API and the yellow stripes... I tried using 'flexible' to try and fix but unsuccessful. if anyone can just look at this for me and show me what am missing, I would be really grateful.
'''

```
               import 'dart:async';
           import 'dart:convert';

          import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
           import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Book Search'),
    );
  }
}

class BookListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookListItem({
    this.thumbnail,
    this.title,
    this.releaseDate,
    this.author,
  });

  final Widget thumbnail;
  final String title;
  final String releaseDate;
  final String author;

  @override
  _BookListItemState createState() => _BookListItemState();
}

class _BookListItemState extends State<BookListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 18.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: widget.thumbnail,
          ),
          const Icon(
            Icons.more_vert,
            size: 16.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String search = "a";
  String userSearch = "";
  String aURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  Object get jsonData => null;
  filtersearch(String text) {
    setState(() {
      if (text != "") {
        this.search = text;
      }
    });
  }

  validate(data, opdata) {
    if (data == null) {
      return opdata;
    }

    return data;
  }

  //fetch data from api
  Future<List<Book>> _getUsers() async {
    //use this site to generate json data

    print(this.search + " search");
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + this.search;
    var data = await http.get(url);

    //convert response to json Object
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    //Store data in User list from JsonData
    List<Book> books = [];
    for (var item in jsonData["items"]) {
      Book book = new Book(
          item["volumeInfo"]["title"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["authors"][0],
          item["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]);

      //add data to  object

      books.add(book);
    }

    //return user list
    return books;
  }

  Icon seaicon = Icon(Icons.search);

  Widget seabar = Text(
    "My Book Search Bar",
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: seabar,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: seaicon,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (this.seaicon.icon == Icons.search) {
                      this.seaicon = Icon(Icons.cancel);
                      this.seabar = TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Search",
                        ),
                        onSubmitted: (String userInput) {
                          setState(() {
                            print(userInput);
                            if (userInput != "") {
                              this.search = userInput;
                            } else {
                              this.search = "a";
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      this.seaicon = Icon(Icons.search);
                      this.seabar = Text("AppBar");
                    }
                  });
                })
          ]),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getUsers(),
            // ignore: missing_return
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 90.0,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Card(
                      child: new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new Row(
                          children: [
                            new CircleAvatar(
                              child:
                                  Image.network(snapshot.data[index].thumbnail),
                              maxRadius: 50,
                            ),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0)),
                            new Text(
                              snapshot.data[index].title +
                                  "\n" +
                                  snapshot.data[index].author +
                                  "\n" +
                                  snapshot.data[index].publishedDate,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                              maxLines: 3,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      width: 160,
                      height: 150,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                  Colors.purple),
                            ),
                            width: 70,
                            height: 70,
                          ),
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              'Loading Book List...',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 90,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'no result founds',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Text(
                  'no result founds',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// on tap to show details
class BookDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;
  BookDetails(this.book);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Book Search"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Title: " + book.title),
              Text("Subtitle: " + book.subtitle),
              Text("Thumbnail: " + book.thumbnail),
              Text("Author: " + book.author),
              Text("Published Date: " + book.publishedDate),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Book Class
class Book {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String thumbnail;
  final String author;
  final String publishedDate;

//Constructor to intitilize
  Book(this.title, this.subtitle, this.thumbnail, this.author,
      this.publishedDate);

  static void add(Book book) {}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below

Step 1: You need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` , because json for image link use `http`

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="so_issue557"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Your json result for image

```
"imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=o19zBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=o19zBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
```

Step 2: Wrap `Text` with `Expanded`

```
Expanded(
          child: Text(
            snapshot.data[index].title +
                "\n" +
                snapshot.data[index].author +
                "\n" +
                snapshot.data[index].publishedDate,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            maxLines: 3,
          ),
        ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Book Search'),
    );
  }
}

class BookListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookListItem({
    this.thumbnail,
    this.title,
    this.releaseDate,
    this.author,
  });

  final Widget thumbnail;
  final String title;
  final String releaseDate;
  final String author;

  @override
  _BookListItemState createState() => _BookListItemState();
}

class _BookListItemState extends State<BookListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 18.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: widget.thumbnail,
          ),
          const Icon(
            Icons.more_vert,
            size: 16.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String search = "a";
  String userSearch = "";
  String aURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  Object get jsonData => null;
  filtersearch(String text) {
    setState(() {
      if (text != "") {
        this.search = text;
      }
    });
  }

  validate(data, opdata) {
    if (data == null) {
      return opdata;
    }

    return data;
  }

  //fetch data from api
  Future<List<Book>> _getUsers() async {
    //use this site to generate json data

    print(this.search + " search");
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + this.search;
    var data = await http.get(url);

    //convert response to json Object
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    //Store data in User list from JsonData
    List<Book> books = [];
    for (var item in jsonData["items"]) {
      Book book = Book(
          item["volumeInfo"]["title"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"],
          item["volumeInfo"]["authors"][0],
          item["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]);

      //add data to  object

      books.add(book);
    }

    //return user list
    return books;
  }

  Icon seaicon = Icon(Icons.search);

  Widget seabar = Text(
    "My Book Search Bar",
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: seabar,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: seaicon,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (this.seaicon.icon == Icons.search) {
                      this.seaicon = Icon(Icons.cancel);
                      this.seabar = TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Search",
                        ),
                        onSubmitted: (String userInput) {
                          setState(() {
                            print(userInput);
                            if (userInput != "") {
                              this.search = userInput;
                            } else {
                              this.search = "a";
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      this.seaicon = Icon(Icons.search);
                      this.seabar = Text("AppBar");
                    }
                  });
                })
          ]),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getUsers(),
            // ignore: missing_return
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 90.0,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              child:
                                  Image.network(snapshot.data[index].thumbnail),
                              maxRadius: 50,
                            ),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0)),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data[index].title +
                                    "\n" +
                                    snapshot.data[index].author +
                                    "\n" +
                                    snapshot.data[index].publishedDate,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                maxLines: 3,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      width: 160,
                      height: 150,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor:
                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.purple),
                            ),
                            width: 70,
                            height: 70,
                          ),
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              'Loading Book List...',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 90,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'no result founds',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Text(
                  'no result founds',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// on tap to show details
class BookDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;
  BookDetails(this.book);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Book Search"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Title: " + book.title),
              Text("Subtitle: " + book.subtitle),
              Text("Thumbnail: " + book.thumbnail),
              Text("Author: " + book.author),
              Text("Published Date: " + book.publishedDate),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Book Class
class Book {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String thumbnail;
  final String author;
  final String publishedDate;

//Constructor to intitilize
  Book(this.title, this.subtitle, this.thumbnail, this.author,
      this.publishedDate);

  static void add(Book book) {}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I'm really grateful and appreciative. There is new error now "Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=lD74bDG3O5oC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"

Comment: please see step1, add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.